# Why doesnt the "Script" option show up on right clicking in the desktop in Ubuntu 12.10? How to make it appear?

Tags: nautilus, scripts

When you right click on a Linux desktop, a menu appears which contains entries like "New folder", "Change desktop background", "Paste", "Scripts", etc. But on a fresh install in Ubuntu 12.10, the "Scripts" option is not showing. I suspect it has something to do with the updated "Nautilus File Manager" software. Is it possible to turn on the script option so that I can execute scripts with a single click?
Thank you ...

Comment: you just want to edit the right-click menu?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in ubuntu 12.10 running *Gnome nautilus 3.6.3*

**Scripts not showing in right click menu**

- Try and place your scripts in the
  `/home/username/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` directory
- Allow
  script to be run by nautilus with the command `sudo chmod +x
  filename_of_script`
- Now Reboot to reload nautilus

This should enable scripts when right clicking on a folder or a file.

**Create New File not showing in right click menu**

- open gedit with `sudo gedit`
- when the blank document is open in gedit press "file" then "save as"
  store the blank file in the `/home/username/Template` folder, save it as "Empty File"
- Now Reboot to reload nautilus
- This should enable "New Document" > "Empty file" when right clicking in folder/on desktop

I am trying to get scripts showing on desktop right click, if i manage i will post an update.

I Hope my answer helped you out

Comment: This solution for scripts not showing in right click menu works for Nautilus 3.8.x as well

Answer (score 0):

Scripts menu(on right-click popup menu) will appear if you add some scripts file to ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts.You can install Ubuntu Tweak and you can add some certain scripts to this director easily or add your script's file to this folder.

Comment: This only works for Nautilus < 3.6 for Nautilus >= 3.6 place scripts into ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts